# TWRequest in background

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading

```
- (void)fetchImages {
    if (self.profileImages == nil) {
        self.profileImages = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:200];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
        for (id tweet in self.timeline) {
            TWRequest *fetchUserImageRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image/%@", [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"user.screen_name"]]] parameters:nil requestMethod:TWRequestMethodGET];
            [fetchUserImageRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 200) {
                    [self.profileImages setObject:[UIImage imageWithData:responseData] forKey:[tweet valueForKeyPath:@"user.screen_name"]];
                    NSArray *indexPath = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.timeline indexOfObject:tweet] inSection:0]];
                    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
                }
            }];
        }
    });
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FavoriteCell"];

    // configure cell
    id tweet = [self.timeline objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    UILabel *tweetLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    tweetLabel.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"text"];
    UILabel *usernameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
    usernameLabel.text = [tweet valueForKeyPath:@"user.name"];
    UIImageView *profileImage = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    profileImage.image = [self.profileImages objectForKey:[tweet valueForKeyPath:@"user.screen_name"]];
    UILabel *dateLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:103];
    NSString *labelString = [[tweet objectForKey:@"created_at"] substringToIndex:10];
    dateLabel.text = labelString;

    return cell;

}
```

I get the timeline then want to get the profile images for all of users in the timeline. I need to loop through the tweets and get the image. I'm curious how I can determine when all of the images have been fetched then reload the tableview. As of now this isn't happening. The TWRequest is running after the table is reloaded. What am I doing wrong here? Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I updated the method above to reflect what it currently stands as when I'm receiving the error below.

Comment: Edited my response, forget the beginUpdates/endUpdates. I think it should all be solved now.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. This is also what I tried since I know UI updates are supposed to be handled by the main thread but the same error. I will have to investigate it a bit more on my own. I'm not sure why the table view update is inconsistent. This method should be okay.

Comment: It should, without having the code is hard to help you out at this point, I'll give you a vote up. I too would like to know the answer at this point.

Comment: I appreciate it. Using [self.tableView reloadData] produces the results I want, but I'm just not sure if it's too consuming, or too much.

Comment: reloadData has two problems, first it will reload all your cells, in your case this is unnecessary, the 2nd problem is animations, if you only reload a cell the animation is smoother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because [TWRequest performRequestWithHandler:] is an async method. Why do you need to reload the entire table? Why not just reload the cell when you get a image (in the end of your handler block).

If you really want to reload the entire table just keep a count of all your finished requests, and reload the table when all is done.

If you want to reload a single cell you can do something like:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_queue_get_main(), ^{

     [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:0];

}
```

Comment: I get only updating the specific row but calling
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:]; 
doesn't work since there's no way to keep an index of what row to update since this variable isn't updated on a reliable bases.

Comment: Wouldn't the row be something like [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.timeline indexForObject:tweet] inSection:0]?

Comment: Yeah, I managed to get that in there to update the proper row but it's still throwing this error when trying to update the table - "Invalid table view update. The application has requested an update to the table view that is inconsistent with the state provided by the data source."

Comment: Are you using [UITableView beginUpdates] and [UITableView endUpdates]? And the 2nd parameter of reload is not a boolean...

Comment: I am not using beginUpdates and endUpdates - this didn't help. Yeah, the second parameter was UITableViewRowAnimationNone. Above was a typo.

Comment: Can you post your datasource method cellForTableView:...?

Comment: I posted the method above. I set the number of rows to the number of tweets in the timeline, right now it only grabs 20. This doesn't change. I call to update it and get the error I mentioned above. Thanks for all the responses btw.

Comment: It should be dispatch_async not dispatch_sync

Comment: @daidai Nop, the performRequestWithHandler block is already executing in a separate thread. And you want to update the UI on the main thread.